# Akka TCP client: How can I send a message over TCP using akka actor

Tags: scala, sockets, tcp, akka, akka-io

I want to send textual messages over TCP. Pretty easy. I want to do so with akka. I read this article about akka IO:
http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/io-tcp.html

The article present a simple implementation of a TCP client, but it's not clear to me how I would use this client.

1. The constructor takes an InetSocketAddress and an ActorRef. InetSocketAddress make sense (I assume this is the of the destination) but what's the ActorRef? this is my first time using akka, but from what I understand, ActorRef is the reference of another actor. Since my TCP client is an actor, and I expect this TCP actor to communicate with a TCP server, not with another actor, why would I give it an actor ref?
2. what's the props function in the companion object for?
3. once instantiated, how would I use this actor to send TCP messages? Should I just send it a message with the data I want to send in the form of a ByteString?

4.
what's the connection / difference between

```
case Received(data) => 
    listener ! data
```

and

```
case data: ByteString =>
    connection ! Write(data)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Answering your questions:

1. The constructor `class Client(remote: InetSocketAddress, listener: ActorRef) extends Actor` takes a `listener` which is a reference to an actor that is using this `Client` to communicate with remote server. Listener will send and receive messages through this `Client`. Since `Client` is an actor you will communicate with it solely by sending messages. The same applies to the `Client` when it communicates with `connection`/remote - it will send and receive messages on your behalf and forward them to the `listener` you provided.
2. `props` function in a companion object of an actor class is usually used as a helper function for constructing an actor. It's needed if your actor takes constructor arguments and you have to take care not to close over mutable state. Remember you can't use `new` operator to create actors, you have to call `Props`.
3. Your `Client` actor will receive messages of type `ByteString` as in `case data: ByteString =>` once connected to the remote. It will write that data to the TCP connection - effectively sending a message. Whenever it receives a response from remote of type `Received` as in `case Received(data) =>` it will forward it to your `listener` actor.
4. See 3. `Client` actor receives messages from your `listener` and from `connection` and forwards them accordingly. It does not check however where they came from. So whenever it receives `ByteString` it will send it to `connection`/remote, and whenever it receives `Received` it will send bytes to `listener`. You need to make sure your listener can receive these messages if you want to have 2 way communication.

To summarize here is how 2-way communication looks like.

Send `ByteString` to remote:

**MyActor -> `ByteString` -> Client -> `Write(ByteString)` -> connection/remote**

Receive `ByteString` from remote (server talks to client):

**connection/remote -> `Received(ByteString)` -> Client -> `ByteString` -> MyActor**

where '->' is a message send.

Comment: Nice explanation! Strange that I didn't understand the whole process from the doc description itself.