# Scala Actor difference between case msg: ByteString and case Received(msg)

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I have an actor definition as follows:

```
class ClientHandler(connection: ActorRef) extends Actor {

  def receive = {
    case Received(data) => {

      val clientId = data.utf8String.stripLineEnd
      Connector.saveConnection(clientId, self)

      context.become {

       case msg: ByteString => connection ! Write(msg)   

       case Received(msg) => connection ! Write(msg)

      }

    }
    case None =>
  }

}
```

There is a parent actor that is listening for clients that want to connect to a TCP server. Once a client connects, the parent actor instantiates a `ClientHandler` and gives it the original connection so that the `ClientHandler` can talk to the connected client directly.

There is another actor that pushes notifications to clients. That actor looks up clients by ID via Connector that returns an `ActorRef` to an instance of `ClientHandler` and then sends a ByteString using the `!` operator. Like this:

```
val clientConn = Connector.getConnection(userId)
clientConn match {
  case Some(conn) => conn ! payload
  case None =>
}
```

I was pretty sure that whenever such a notification is pushed I can receive it in `ClientHandler` using the `case Received(msg)` within the `become` block, but it didn't work. Instead the `case msg: ByteString` works, but I don't understand why and what the difference between those two is.

I read the documentation for the `Received` method and it says `Whenever data are read from a socket...` does it mean that the `Received` method will be matched only when the remote client writes something (because he writes to a socket), but when another actor (in this case one that is running on the same machine; where does this write go if not to a socket too?) writes something the `case msg: ByteString` will be matched?

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/a/33748534/4982884 (esp points 3 & 4)?

Comment: Probably you should treat them differently as they have different meanings. `Received` is when the client received data from the remote, but `msg: ByteString` is when you wanna send data to the remote. Maybe read the [docs](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/io-tcp.html?language=scala) one more time?

Comment: @NaderGhanbari The docs on TCP doesn't describe what `Received` and `data: ByteString` in either "connecting" or "accepting connections" do. I thought `Received` would be used for receiving messages from the remote and from other actors. Apparently when using a TCP actor `Received` is triggered only upon receiving something from the remote and `msg: ByteString` when receiving a `ByteString` from another actor.